Wildfly: gRPC Server Interceptor for Keycloak oAuth Token
I have a Wildfly Server running an EJB Application, if i make a REST client call to the Application the EJB Security contex has being automatically filled up with a valid Principal and I can cast it to Keycloak Security Context and get Claim informations.
The Application also accept gRCP calls, in this case the the Security context has Anonymous Principal which, I suppose, is because it has not being filled up when gRCP calls come in.
Do I have to implement a global gRPC Server Interceptor?
Is there an Example that I can follow?

This is probably happening because, unlike REST endpoints, gRPC doesn’t automatically integrate with Keycloak on WildFly.
To solve this, you’ll likely need a global ServerInterceptor for gRPC to manage the authentication and authorization. This interceptor will let you extract and verify tokens from the metadata of incoming calls. Normally, you'd look for a Bearer token in the metadata headers and validate it against Keycloak.
You may want to implement somewhat like this:
import io.grpc.*;
import org.keycloak.adapters.jboss.KeycloakPrincipal;
import org.keycloak.representations.AccessToken;

public class KeycloakAuthInterceptor implements ServerInterceptor {
    @Override
    public <ReqT, RespT> ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> interceptCall(
            ServerCall<ReqT, RespT> call,
            Metadata headers,
            ServerCallHandler<ReqT, RespT> next) {

        // Retrieve the Authorization header
        String token = headers.get(Metadata.Key.of("Authorization", Metadata.ASCII_STRING_MARSHALLER));
        if (token == null || !token.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            call.close(Status.UNAUTHENTICATED.withDescription("Authorization token missing"), headers);
            return new ServerCall.Listener<ReqT>() {};
        }

        token = token.substring("Bearer ".length());

        try {
            // Verify token and populate security context
            AccessToken accessToken = verifyTokenWithKeycloak(token);
            if (accessToken == null) {
                call.close(Status.UNAUTHENTICATED.withDescription("Invalid token"), headers);
                return new ServerCall.Listener<ReqT>() {};
            }

            // Populate the security context (example uses WildFly's SecurityContext)
            SecurityContext context = createSecurityContext(accessToken);
            SecurityContextAssociation.setSecurityContext(context);

            // Continue the gRPC call
            return Contexts.interceptCall(Context.current(), call, headers, next);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            call.close(Status.UNAUTHENTICATED.withDescription("Failed to authenticate"), headers);
            return new ServerCall.Listener<ReqT>() {};
        }
    }

    private AccessToken verifyTokenWithKeycloak(String token) {
        // Implement token verification with Keycloak here
        return null;  // Replace with actual token verification logic
    }

    private SecurityContext createSecurityContext(AccessToken accessToken) {
        // Convert AccessToken to WildFly SecurityContext with KeycloakPrincipal
        KeycloakPrincipal<?> principal = new KeycloakPrincipal<>("principal-name");
        // Set up the security context and return it
        return new SecurityContext(principal);
    }
}

